# How does redirecting work in PageSpeed-Insights?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

When I test my mobile website with my full URL: https://www.managerup.com I got a very good result on the PageSpeed-Insights.

When I enter however only managerup.com, Page Speed Insights redirects it to http://managerup.com and the score drops significantly on the mobile score.

Why is that?

By the way, in any browser, the redirecting from managerup.com to https://www.managerup.com works perfectly.

Why doesn't it work in Page Speed Insights?

Comment: What/who are you using for redirecting? I use Cloudflare and because of that my scoring ends up way lower when I do not fill in the correct URL, though, if I fill in the address of azure it gives me way better results.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, **www**.site.com is different from site.com, and any redirect 301 / CNAME setting should influence it in negative, for an obvious reason: you need one more step than standard one. Usually any domain has a domain canonical version, and you can find it [here](https://httpstatus.io/).

Usually PSI test exactly URL you give it, and score may be influenced by it - i.e *[example.it](https://example.it/)* is generally different from [www.example.it](https://example.it/). If you configure at its best domain "variants", every single step may be taken into account for PSI.

You need also that [rel=canonical attribute](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls) is right respect on it.
301 redirect would take *worst* (not better) PSI score than direct URL.
You should optimize website using a single, by default, single version.